# Understanding `history` for bash

Tags: bash, history

Yesterday I `ssh`-d into my RemoteFS and performed some commands.

Today they do not appear in the history. Frustrating, as it took some time to look at the commands I used.

I frequently get this problem. I suspect that using the same login for multiple simultaneous terminal sessions maybe results in a separate history for each. And changing the user (e.g. elevating to superuser) opens up a different set of histories.

Could someone explain scientifically the life-cycle of history?  When does a new one get created? How to access/view all the existing ones?  And under what circumstances does history get destroyed? Do they ever get amalgamated?

Comment: `man bash` has a section on HISTORY.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1288/16178

Comment: Use `sudo(8)` to log your commands as another user.  Use `script(1)` to simply log your terminal session.  Shell history is useful for navigation, but you can't rely on it to keep trace of everything you do.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on variable settings, but by default there is only one history file per user, not per terminal session.

The history is nowadays held in an in-memory buffer and only written out to the history file when the buffer is full or on logout.  Therefore multiple terminal sessions under the same user can overwrite each other's history.  The history system is not really suitable for multiple sessions under the same user id.

If you want to keep sessions separate, modify variable `HISTFILE`.

It might seem neat to set:

```
HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history$$"
```

where `$$` gives the current PID.  While this gives each terminal session  its own history, it quickly becomes a maintenance nightmare with all those history files floating around.

There are other variables that control history, see `man bash` for a description.  You can also:

```
set | grep '^HIST'
```

which might be instructive.

Don't be tempted to edit the history file with a text editor.  It is a binary file (contains non-text fields) and can be easily trashed.

*When does a new one get created?* First time a history filename is used.

*How to access/view all the existing ones?* Depends what name you have given them.

*And under what circumstances does history get destroyed?* When `HISTSIZE` is exceeded (default is 500 lines).  Only `HISTSIZE` lines are stored.  Remember that the file itself is overwritten only when the in-memory buffer is full, or on logout.  However we do have the `histappend` option:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

which will append the session rather than overwrite.  Be careful using this, you could end-up with a huge history file.

*Do they ever get amalgamated?*  No, not unless you write a script to do it, or you set `histappend`.

Comment: My `.bash_history` is a text file (albeit UTF-8 encoded).

Comment: Running `history -a` from within `PROMPT_COMMAND` can help merge history across multiple sessions, although you may not always like the resulting linearization (especially if you are working actively in multiple sessions at a time).

Comment: @chepner:  I have to admit that I was looking at a korn shell (ksh93) history file, where the line number is a binary `int`.   Yes, appending multiple sessions in my opinion would not be useful.